# Sails.js load object in all views

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have a simple website with a main menu. The menu has categories like "T-Shirts, Shoes and Accessories...". But its dynamic. All of these categories are in a Model "Category" and the words can be different.

So, how can I have this menu rendered on every page without passing data to the view on every controller like:

```
Category.find(function(err, categories){
    res.view({categories: categories});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define your header in a separate file call it as header.html and include it in layout.ejs using

```
<% include ../includes/header.html %>
```

And show appropriate menus on each page depending on the condition whether it should be displayed to normal user or admin by adding roles field to category collection.

Comment: I'm doing that. Include the header its not a problem. I want to show the same menu in all pages.

Comment: you will have to pass the query object you can't avoid that.We will need more code to understand your problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on all pages, it might be easiest to write a customer middleware function in `config/http.js` that adds `categories` to the local variables.

See [sails docs - adding-or-overriding-http-middleware](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/middleware#?adding-or-overriding-http-middleware)